# Wordpress adding s in http

Tags: php, wordpress

I am modifying Wordpress and everytime I save it in Editor, it changes links from http to https. How to stop that? It makes absolutely no sense!

Comment: What is the protocol set (http:// or https://) in your site URL present in Settings -> General? If it's https://, your site is rewriting all the URLs due to that.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: Yes, it's https, but how to stop this madness of URLs rewriting? Who came out with this idea?!

Comment: Writing a more detailed answer. Hold on!

Comment: I guess this solved your problem ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress (and many other CMS and frameworks) will automatically rewrite your URLs to conserve the protocol you are viewing the page as. This is for a variety of reasons, the strongest of which being something called **secure cookie directives**. In short, PHP allows you to set HTTPS cookies, or HTTP cookies, but generally not both at the same time.

To counter this, Wordpress segregates your visitors to one protocol. It does so by prefixing all the URLs it generates with the config setting set in Settings -> General under Wordpress Address. If this is set to https://, all the links Wordpress generates will be starting with this URL (apart from offsite links).

If this bothers you, you can change it there. There are also ways to make Wordpress smarter through plug-ins. Have a look to see if you find one that allows you to do what a *smart* framework does and to keep your HTTP clients on HTTP and HTTPS on HTTPS. It is worth doing if your site allows both, though I would keep everything on https if I were you - it's safer for the user due to end-to-end encryption and authentication.